# Richtmyer Meshkov instability in MHD

Tags: plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Richtmyer Meshkov instability in MHD](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/richtmyer-meshkov-instability-in-mhd)

The Richtmyer Meshkov instability in Hydrodynamics:-
1) When shock wave interacts with the contact discontinuity, it accumulates the vorticity on the CD
2) This causes the density discontinuity to curl up, and form series of vortices

In application of the longitudinal magnetic field with conducting fluid as the working medium,

1) The RM instability is suppressed 
2) Series of new shocks is formed and it carries away the vorticity

My question is ,
what exactly happens in Magneto-Hydrodynamic system?
Why the RM instability is supressed?
How can one get the physical intuition of what is happening at the interface?

Comment: somehow, this question is shown twice on this community. I had asked this on computational science community, it got migrated.  here is the other link http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/richtmyer-meshkov-instability-in-mhd

Comment: BTW, @smj, You should be able to close and delete your own questions as long as they have no answers.